# recorded as an Atlantic hurricane made landfall

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> When Hurricane Dorian slammed into Great Abaco Island in the Bahamas on September 1, instruments measured the speed of its furious winds at 185 mph—tying the legendary Labor Day hurricane of 1935 for the highest wind speeds recorded **as an Atlantic hurricane made landfall**

---

Is it a clause, "as" is a conjuction? or is it a noun phrase, "as" is a preposition? What does it mean?

Comment: Let me rephrase this according to my understanding ..........tying with the legendary Labor Day hurricane of 1935 for the highest wind speeds recorded when Atlantic hurricanes make landfall

Comment: So, to answer your question, it serves as a conjunction.

Comment: Thank you for helping me